# QGIS error connecting to Crunchy HA PostgreSQL Postgis database via SSL

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, qgis

When i try to establish connection from QGIS to Postgis database using ssl i am getting an error "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "XXX_GIS_POS_DEV". as seen in image[image: error image].

The strange part is that I have not inputted that in the "Username" field. On investigating i found that "XXX_GIS_POS_DEV" was listed as "Common Name" in the certificate which I have saved using the certification manager.

How can i force QGIS to use username i have keyed in.

Comment: have you tried copying the certificates to the folder `.postgresql/` in your home directory? libq will look for the certificates there in case none were provided in the connection string. maybe worth trying it out ;)

Comment: What line in the pg_hba file matches your log in?  Are you trying to use client certs, or just server certs?  Can you connect with something else, like `psql`?

Comment: sorry new to QGIS and Postgis. I am using QGIS wizard so there is no logs. The above error message is from the wizard.

Comment: Ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and could not fix it properly. We have a postgresql managed instance on Google Cloud Platform, with SSL required. I created the SSL client certificate with a certain name, which seemed to be hardcoded in the certificate itself. QGIS picks this up, and thinks this is also the pg-username.

An ugly workaround: create a pg-user with the same name as your client-certificate, or (--did not test this one--) create a new certificate with the pg-username as cert-name.

Authentication in QGIS through PKI-paths with client-cert.pem and client-key.pem.